# Using IntentFilter

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use IntentFilter with Brodcastreciver, but text not updates.

I want to update text every time when time changes. Better if when day changes, but I dont know how to do this.

Can you help me please to do it right?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
            .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
            .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
            .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(helper.createView(this));
    initCard();

    initHeader();
    helper.initActionBar(this);

    IntentFilter s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver, s_intentFilter);
    initHeader();
}

private void initHeader() {
    TextView title = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.title));
    final TextView subtitle = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.subtitle));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy.HHmmss");
    final String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    subtitle.setText(currentDateandTime);

}
private final BroadcastReceiver m_timeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK))
        {
            initHeader();
        }
    }
};
```

**Update**: Time changes. Sorry)
Actually it is chnges every minute

Comment: Please also post your AndroidManifest file. Have you added the intent-filter there? Edit: forget what I said, you register the receiver in the code already.

Comment: @tknell I found that it is works. I dont put filters in manifest. Also change to ACTION_DATE_CHANGED